# Why 'Are "toddler" and "baby" mutually exclusive?' was migrated

Tags: discussion, migration

Why was ["Are 'toddler' and 'baby' mutually exclusive?"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/are-toddler-and-baby-mutually-exclusive) migrated? This is a legitimate question asking about the use of the English words *toddler* and *baby* in everyday life. In fact in its form it is not even suitable for Parenting SE in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migration reversed after having talked with a Parenting mod in [TL](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2555359#2555359) (SE mods only).   It is, after all, a question about *terminology*.

Comment: It seems to have been migrated back again??

Comment: It was migrated back by Jeff Atwood himself. I guess the mods don't get a choice...

Comment: @simchona: I guess it doesn't really matter, I was just puzzled given waiwai's comment.